# Не работает DHCP в сетевом мосте Virtualbox

Tags: linux, сеть, dhcp

Создал сетевой интерфейс в /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto vip
iface vip inet static
address 11.11.11.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
bridge_ports none
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_fd 1
```

Выбрал эту сеть в качестве сетевого моста - гостевая система на вин7 не может получить локальный IP

Задача запустить DHCP сервер в этой подсети

Comment: Понимания в этом деле мало, делаю из кучи разный мануалов (

Comment: А чем не устроил сетевой мост с существующей сетевухой?